# Can the Angular production build not shorten class names?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, typescript-decorator

Is it possible to tell the Angular production build not to shorten class names?

Something like `ng serve -o --prod=true --abbreviateClassName=false

The issue I'm having is that I'm using this library:

https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/

It allows us to decorate class properties in order to validate them.

Since Angular shortens the class names I'm getting errors like this:

```
main.2876a5e2eb85f08784d9.js:1 Uncaught Error: The ValidationContainer 
      already contains context with signature t_e_sku.
    at Function.t.addValidationContext
```

The decorators are keyed by `ConstructorName_propertyName` and since the Angular production build shortens the name this introduces conflicts when creating the validation contexts per the decorators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try disabling optimization:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

```sh
ng serve --prod --optimization=false
```

There is also an `optimization` flag for the builder configuration in the `angular.json` file:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "optimization": false
```

I'm not exactly sure if this flag is the same as the above.

I'm sure this will increase the bundle sizes. There aren't any finer grain controls here for this sort of thing, and I don't think a custom builder will help.

We haven't had the `ng eject` option to create a custom WebPack build for a while, but you might find some online examples of how to do it manually. It'll be a pain to update when Angular 9 comes out.

Maybe this library you're using was intended for NodeJS and not web browsers.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a shot! - I'm the author of the library so it's definitely intended for browsers :)